# Terraform - merge list of object variable into list of values

Tags: terraform

I am trying to change the following list of objects variable to be more generic and global.
**principal_name** need to be a list of strings.

```
// Current version of account_assignments variable
variable "account_assignments" {
  type = list(object({
    permission_set_name = string
    permission_set_arn  = string
    principal_name      = list(string)
    principal_type      = string
  }))
  default = [
    // ViewOnlyAccess
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-31d20e5987f0ce66",
      permission_set_name = "ViewOnlyAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Developers01"
    },
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-31d20e5987f0ce66",
      permission_set_name = "ViewOnlyAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Developers02"
    },
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-31d20e5987f0ce66",
      permission_set_name = "ViewOnlyAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Developers03"
    },
    // AdministratorAccess
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-955c264e8f20fea3",
      permission_set_name = "AdministratorAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Administrators01"
    },
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-955c264e8f20fea3",
      permission_set_name = "AdministratorAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Administrators02"
    },
    {
      permission_set_arn  = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-0000000000000000/ps-955c264e8f20fea3",
      permission_set_name = "AdministratorAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = "Administrators03"
    },
  ]
}
```

The Terraform variable below is the NEW version of account_assignments variable I want.
As you can see the principal_name key changed to list of strings

```
variable "account_assignments" {
  type = list(object({
    permission_set_name = string
    permission_set_arn  = string
    principal_name      = list(string)
    principal_type      = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      permission_set_arn  = var.viewOnlyARN,
      permission_set_name = "ViewOnlyAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = ["Developers01", "Developers02", "Developers03"]
    },
    {
      permission_set_arn  = var.AdminOnlyARN,
      permission_set_name = "AdministratorAccess",
      principal_type      = "GROUP",
      principal_name      = ["Administrators01", "Administrators02", "Administrators03"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: I'm using this variable inside aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.this using for_each
***main.tf***

```
locals {
  assignment_map = {
    for a in var.account_assignments :
    format("%v-%v-%v", substr(a.principal_type, 0, 1), a.principal_name, a.permission_set_name) => a
  }
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "this" {
  for_each = local.assignment_map

  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  permission_set_arn = each.value.permission_set_arn

  principal_id   = each.value.principal_type == "GROUP" ? data.aws_identitystore_group.this[each.value.principal_name].id : data.aws_identitystore_user.this[each.value.principal_name].id
  principal_type = each.value.principal_type

  target_id   = aws_organizations_account.account.id
  target_type = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
}
```

I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Your `variable "account_assignments"` is incorrect. You can't have `var.viewOnlyARN`  in there, nor it matches your type. So what exactly is your question? How to fix your `variable "account_assignments"` ?

Comment: The question is how can I change to Key principal_name to be a list of strings?

Comment: Sorry, its not clear. What's wrong with your current code? I guess it does not even run, due to all the errors in `variable "account_assignments"`.?

Comment: Also, you've set the `principal_name = string` and you said you want a list of strings.

Comment: I fixed the type of principal_name to be list(string). I need your help and assistance to understand what should I change within aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.this because right now I'm using for_each = local.assignment_map and don't know how to create a nested loop so I can get principal_name values